# How to get screenshot only external monitor?

Tags: applescript, screen-capture

I there any way to screenshot only external monitor screen?

```
do shell script "screencapture -x " & shot_path
```

Comment: A little more information would help. Are you trying to take a screen shot of the whole screen or just a window?

Comment: If you register one of your accounts we can merge them for you. We also have a self-service merging tool here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/account

Answer (score 1):

**Manually**, you can always use <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> and select the area you want.

## OR

For **Applescript**, check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764072/screen-capture-with-applescript

> set imagePath to (path to desktop as text) & "screenCapture.png" do
>   shell script "screencapture -mx -T0 " & quoted form of POSIX path of
>   imagePath

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd> takes a screen shot of the whole screen!

Comment: The question was how to "screenshot only external monitor screen." Cmd + Shift + 3 captures both screens.

Answer (score 1):

If it's the main display, you could use `screencapture -m`. Or if you know its coordinates, `screencapture -Rx,y,w,h` (rect) captures a specified area.

`-R` is only shown in the help message and not on the man page.

`system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType` shows information about connected displays. `osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to bounds of window of desktop'` shows the combined dimensions of displays.

Answer (score 0):

Use  <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> and select all the screen.